# Android Force GridView items to fill full gridview height

Tags: android, gridview, height, android-gridview

First of all I'd like to say it isn't any duplicate. My problem is tha I have to much items and I want to make them smaller to fill in gridview height. That's why I cannot use `setMinimumHeight`. I need something like `setMaximumHeight` but nothing like this is predicted by Android SDK. Additionally I don't have any row spacing so I cannot make it smaller.

image to help understand:

[image]

I want make itemw smaller height, I don't want any to be "cut" by the display border.

Comment: I'd calculate the required height in runtime by dividing GridView height by rows number, and setting each item's height equal to result.

Comment: @VladMatvienko I've already tried this, but with no effect. I dunno, maybe in xml I am to add sth?

Comment: If no effect, then you've done something wrong

Comment: @VladMatvienko : Can you plz post your code so we can get an idea.

Comment: The problem is, GridView isn't the only View in activity. The activity has few thing over and below GridView, set to `wrap_content`, co calculating is at least impossible.